# Ambiguous error with char* and char[N]

Tags: c++, templates

Can someone help me to understand is this correct behavior or not.

Consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct test {
};

template <typename T>
bool operator==(const test<T>& obj, const T* arr) {
    return true;
}

template <typename T, size_t TN>
bool operator==(const test<T>& obj, const T (&arr)[TN]) {
    return false;
}

int main() {
    cout << ( test<char>() == "string" ) <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

With gcc 4.7.3 it compiles just fine and outputs '0' as expected.

But with Visual Studio compiler it reports an `ambiguous error (C2593)`.

Who is right in this situation and what does `standard` say about it?

Thank you.

Comment: It's ambiguous, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using fairly recent versions (i.e., recent heads of the development branches) of [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) also show an ambiguity. I would have thought that the overload taking an array is better but it seem the code is ambiguous. I haven't tracked down the relevant clauses in the standard, yet, however.

Comment: +1 I'm fairly sure it is driven by 14.8.2.4 `[temp.deduct.partial]`, and 14.5.6.2 `[temp.func.order]`. To say those sections of the standard are "meaty" would be a gross understatement of epic proportions. None-the-less i've answered a similar question by actually doing that legwork (can't recall it right now) and believe you're correct, so +1.

Comment: The key point is that the rank of the identity and array-to-pointer conversions is the same: *Exact match*, so none of the conversion sequence (no conversion/array-to-pointer) is worse than the other.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand simple overloading would not work in new versions of gcc and already doesn't work in VC10.

So, if someone wonders how to fix this issue here is a solution:

```
template <typename T>
struct test {
};

template <typename T>
struct parse {
};

template <typename T>
struct parse<T*> {
    static bool run() {
        return true;
    }
};

template <typename T, size_t TN>
struct parse<T[TN]> {
    static bool run() {
        return false;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename T2> 
bool operator==(const test<T>& obj, const T2& obj2) {
    return parse<T2>::run();
}

int main() {
    cout << ( test<char>() == "string" ) <<endl;
    cout << ( test<char>() == (char*)"string" ) <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled it with VC10, gcc-4.6.3 and gcc-4.8.1.
Seems to be working correctly.